# web3 module takes nearly 500ms to load

Tags: web3js, nodejs, javascript

I noticed my web3 scripts are very slow and after doing some testing I noticed that the web3 module takes 470ms alone to load.
Other modules only take 1 ms.
Is this normal? I have the latest version of Node and npm. (Node 18.18.0 and npm 9.8.1 )

I am using the module like this:

var Web3 = require('web3');

Also I have to run this script every few seconds, so is there a way to have the Web3 module permanently loaded so I don't have to re-load it every time the script runs?